# Patching multiple commits, multiple branches in GIT

Tags: git

I have been working on some features on the latest version/branch of my project (4.3).

Now I need to port these changes over to an earlier version (4.2). There are a number of commits in the work I have done, including some branching, that i merged back together again.

[image]

4.2 and 4.3 are basically branches that share a common ancestor, however they are stored in different GIT repositories.

I basically want to move all my changes to the master branch in 4.2.

I considered a few things :

- GIT patch - this seems to give the option of how many commits into the past i want to create the patch for, however because I have some branching, this option seems meaningles.
- cherry pick - seems to only deal with single commits.

What is the best way to go about moving my commit/branch structure over?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your 4.3 repository as a remote for the 4.2 repository, then cherry-pick/merge/rebase commits as required.

Comment: I want to create a patch from commit2 to commit8, but I am not sure how to do this. Can I pick two arbitrary poins in the GIT tree and say, give me everything in between?

Comment: Unless you want to squash all of those commits into a single patch, you may want to use rebase instead (which basically sequentially applies commits as patches on top of a given base).

Comment: @OliverWatkins `git cherry-pick commit2~..commit8`

Comment: hmmm seems to not work. $ git cherry-pick 55a52fc~..27b2e7f